# Vue.js I18n not setting language

Tags: javascript, json, promise, vue.js, multilingual

I'm using Vue.js 2 and the [I18n plugin](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) to create a multilanguage website. The required language file (in my example `nl`) is requested from an external url. Unfortunately I can't get it working.

```
function getLanguage() {
  return Vue.http({
    url: '/language/nl_NL.json',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  .then(
    response =>
      response.json(),
    () => {
      /* Error */
    }
  );
}
Vue.config.lang = 'nl';
Vue.locale(Vue.config.lang, getLanguage());
console.log(getLanguage());
```

The `/language/nl_NL.json` file is a json file. The network connection is ok (returns 200) and the `console.log()` command is showing a Promise. But the translation across my website is not working. Vue.locale is not setting the file as a translation file and I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `return response.json()` ?

Comment: I'm already returning Vue.http(), I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: So how you are reading the promise then? I mean it;s a promise, shouldn't you do something like `getLanguage().success(response => response)` or something?

Comment: I think Vue.locale is expecting a Promise: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/dynamic.html